# why does this cause extreme lag in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

when running the p5.js code, it seems to break, it works for 1 frame then breaks and lags no matter what device (ChatGPT and bard were unable to debug) (btw no error message is given)

```
var player;
var speed = 5;

var HP = 10;
var MaxHP = 10;

var frames = 0;

var VillageX = 0;
var VillageY = 0;

var NPCs = [];

class NPC {
    constructor() {
        this.x = getRandomInt(VillageX, VillageX + 500);
        this.y = getRandomInt(VillageY, VillageY + 500);
        
        this.sprite = new Sprite(this.x, this.y, 15);

        this.sprite.img = "Images/npc.png";
        this.sprite.collider = "dynamic";
        this.sprite.scale = 3;
        this.minimapX = 0;
        this.minimapY = 0;

        NPCs.push(this);
    }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}


function preload() {
    lexendFont = loadFont("Fonts/lexend.ttf")
}

function setup() {
    frameRate(60);
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

    frames += 1;
    console.log(frames);

    VillageX = getRandomInt(-4900, 4400);
    VillageY = getRandomInt(-4900, 4400);

    player = new Sprite(0, 0, 15, "circle");
    player.addImage("player", loadImage("Images/player.png"));
    player.scale = 3;
    player.collider = "dynamic";

    topWall = new Sprite(0, -5010, 10000, 10);
    topWall.visible = false;
    topWall.collider = "kinematic";
    
    leftWall = new Sprite(-5010, 0, 10, 10000);
    leftWall.visible = false;
    leftWall.collider = "kinematic";

    bottomWall = new Sprite(0, 5010, 10000, 10);
    bottomWall.visible = false;
    bottomWall.collider = "kinematic";

    rightWall = new Sprite(5010, 0, 10, 10000);
    rightWall.visible = false;
    rightWall.collider = "kinematic";

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        new NPC();
    }

    textSize(32);
}

function draw() {
    
    clear();
    background("green");

    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(8);
    noFill();
    rect(windowWidth - 215, windowHeight - 50, 200, 35, 3);

    noStroke();
    fill("#00cc44");
    rect(windowWidth - 215, windowHeight - 50, map(HP, 0, MaxHP, 0, 200), 35, 3);

    fill("black");
    rect(15, windowHeight - 215, 200, 200, 12);

    var minimapX = map(player.x, -5200, 5200, 15, 215);
    var minimapY = map(player.y, -5200, 5200, windowHeight - 215, windowHeight - 15);
    
    fill("white");
    circle(minimapX, minimapY, 8);

    NPCs.forEach((NP, index) => {
        NP.minimapX = map(NP.x, -5200, 5200, 15, 215);
        NP.minimapY = map(NP.y, -5200, 5200, windowHeight - 215, windowHeight - 15)
        
        fill("blue");
        circle(NP.minimapX, NP.minimapY, 8);
    });

    camera.x = player.x;
    camera.y = player.y;

    player.rotation = player.angleTo(mouse) + 90;

    if (kb.pressing("left")) player.vel.x = -speed;
    else if (kb.pressing("right")) player.vel.x = speed;
    else player.vel.x = 0;

    if (kb.pressing("up")) player.vel.y = -speed;
    else if (kb.pressing("down")) player.vel.y = speed;
    else player.vel.y = 0;

    fill("white");
    textFont(lexendFont)
    textSize(18);
    text("HEALTH", windowWidth - 205, windowHeight - 27)
}
```

It breaks and lags extremely. How do i fix this, i have narrowed it down to be something to do with crearing an NPC, but nothing more.

Comment: Can you please share a p5js editor link? Or some other runnable form, so we can just start debugging the code.

Comment: Sure! https://replit.com/@oLemon/full-survive-project#script.js

Comment: Just a first conclusion: Assigning `this.sprite.img = 'Images/npc.png'` in `NPC`'s `constructor` causes the `setup` function to be called repeatedly. I don't yet understand why, I'm still investigating. Anyway, the solution is to preload the image, as you do with the font. There are the following steps. 1) declare in the outer scope `var npcImg;` 2) in `preload` load the image `npcImg = loadImage('Images/npc.png');` 3) in `setup` add `npcImg.loadPixels();` 4) in `NPC`'s `constructor` change to `this.sprite.img = npcImg;`

Comment: Omg, it works. TYSM for your help, i have been dying to know why it doesnt work. Thank you, i will look into why it calles setup many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was a bug in `p5.js` that was solved in version `1.5.0`.
The [bug #5816](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/5816) consisted in the fact that, in certain conditions, an image loaded during `setup` resulted in the function `setup` being called again (multiple times); in your case, the line `this.sprite.img = 'Images/npc.png'` (from `NPC`'s constructor) resulted in the `setup` function being called on an infinite recursion.

So the immediate solution is, if possible, to **upgrade** the link to `p5.js` in your `index.html` **to the latest version** (`1.6.0`) -- it took me a while to realise that your replit was using version `1.4.0`.

Regardless of that, it is a good practice to preload images, as you already did with fonts. I'll repeat the steps from my message (adapted from [preload reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload)):

1. declare in the outer scope `var npcImg;` (or `let npcImg` if you change to ES6)
2. in `preload` function do load the image `npcImg = loadImage('Images/npc.png');`
3. in `setup` function add `npcImg.loadPixels();`
4. replace `this.sprite.img = 'Images/npc.png'` with `this.sprite.img = npcImg;` (in NPC's constructor)